# How do I create a Client instance on Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I want to add users into the oauth_clients table using Tinker, but I don't know how to create a Client instance on tinker.

Comment: Words and code will greatly help us help you, what oauth implementation are you running?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Client instance? If this is a model, you can try

```
$client = new \App\Client();
```

and then use it

```
$client->name = "Some name";
$client->methodName();
```

etc